# Error: "inconsistent hash". Workers crash and node is unable to connect to others

Tags: node, tezos-client, error

I'm consistently getting the below errors. What stands out is the "inconsistent hash" error, seemingly causing the workers to crash. The hash of the block header and this of the local hash seem to differ. I have no idea what this means though. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
Mar 17 15:14:35 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Unexpected error (validator):
Mar 17 15:14:35 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Error:
Mar 17 15:14:35 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Inconsistent hash:
Mar 17 15:14:35 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:     local: CoWYi7Nmm91pS8ZNXscNTt6uBpNdaWtpantEc3HcV3XASYEVriNS
Mar 17 15:14:35 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:     block_header: CoVHuYH6TpDbJjXFqRsZXichbxdnvqWrDSaGpjVAsJRknAMk8Lkq
Mar 17 15:14:35 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: 
Mar 17 15:14:35 - validator.peer(151): Worker crashed [NetXdQprcVkpa:idsMwfkFJFTX]:
Mar 17 15:14:35 - validator.peer(151): Inconsistent hash:
Mar 17 15:14:35 - validator.peer(151):   local: CoWYi7Nmm91pS8ZNXscNTt6uBpNdaWtpantEc3HcV3XASYEVriNS
Mar 17 15:14:35 - validator.peer(151):   block_header: CoVHuYH6TpDbJjXFqRsZXichbxdnvqWrDSaGpjVAsJRknAMk8Lkq
Mar 17 15:14:35 - validator.peer(152): Worker started for NetXdQprcVkpa:idrhpgmWuEDG
Mar 17 15:14:35 - validator.block: Validation of block BLqhrPaH6WQtVYZssbonME7DPiQLTvZyidkYa8dvAxxoeTsnVKD failed
Mar 17 15:14:35 - validator.block: Pushed: 2019-03-17T15:14:35Z, Treated: 2019-03-17T15:14:35Z, Failed: 2019-03-17T15:14:35Z
Mar 17 15:14:35 - validator.block: Inconsistent hash:
Mar 17 15:14:35 - validator.block:   local: CoWYi7Nmm91pS8ZNXscNTt6uBpNdaWtpantEc3HcV3XASYEVriNS
Mar 17 15:14:35 - validator.block:   block_header: CoVHuYH6TpDbJjXFqRsZXichbxdnvqWrDSaGpjVAsJRknAMk8Lkq
Mar 17 15:14:35 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Unexpected error (validator):
Mar 17 15:14:35 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Error:
Mar 17 15:14:35 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Inconsistent hash:
Mar 17 15:14:35 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:     local: CoWYi7Nmm91pS8ZNXscNTt6uBpNdaWtpantEc3HcV3XASYEVriNS
Mar 17 15:14:35 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:     block_header: CoVHuYH6TpDbJjXFqRsZXichbxdnvqWrDSaGpjVAsJRknAMk8Lkq
Mar 17 15:14:35 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: 
Mar 17 15:14:35 - validator.peer(152): Worker crashed [NetXdQprcVkpa:idrhpgmWuEDG]:
Mar 17 15:14:35 - validator.peer(152): Inconsistent hash:
Mar 17 15:14:35 - validator.peer(152):   local: CoWYi7Nmm91pS8ZNXscNTt6uBpNdaWtpantEc3HcV3XASYEVriNS
Mar 17 15:14:35 - validator.peer(152):   block_header: CoVHuYH6TpDbJjXFqRsZXichbxdnvqWrDSaGpjVAsJRknAMk8Lkq
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue myself. My node had rejected a seemingly valid block. I found this out by listing the rejected blocks of the node:

```
tezos-admin-client list rejected blocks

Output:
Hash: BLqhrPaH6WQtVYZssbonME7DPiQLTvZyidkYa8dvAxxoeTsnVKD
Level: 356181
Error:
Inconsistent hash:
  local: CoWYi7Nmm91pS8ZNXscNTt6uBpNdaWtpantEc3HcV3XASYEVriNS
  block_header: CoVHuYH6TpDbJjXFqRsZXichbxdnvqWrDSaGpjVAsJRknAMk8Lkq
```

So the node rejected the block due to the different hashes of the headers and was not able to catch up, because it likely rejected a valid block.

I solved this issue by unmarking the block:

```
tezos-admin-client unmark invalid BLqhrPaH6WQtVYZssbonME7DPiQLTvZyidkYa8dvAxxoeTsnVKD

Output: 
Block BLqhrPaH6WQtVYZssbonME7DPiQLTvZyidkYa8dvAxxoeTsnVKD no longer marked invalid.
```

I still have no idea why this happened.

Comment: Well done on findint this out and thanks for letting us know! You may want to file a ticket on tezos gitlab for further help on *why* this happened: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues you can always point back to this question.

Comment: Hmmm... I tried this but I got zero invalid blocks.

Comment: Then it's not the same issue as described above.