# How to handle nodes that encounter "Inconsistent hash" failures?

Tags: node, error, snapshots

On April 1st 2020 around Block 890,840 (+/- 20 blocks), a node was seemingly rendered non-operational by looping on a inconsistent hash error. Worth noting that this only occurred on a single node out of a cluster of nodes.

Unlike this [post](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/800/error-inconsistent-hash-workers-crash-and-node-is-unable-to-connect-to-other), there were no rejected blocks.

Node functionality was restored by removing .tezos-node and performing a snapshot import.

Any suggestions on why this may have happened and what to do in case this occurs again?

```
~/tezos$ ./tezos-admin-client list rejected blocks
No invalid blocks.

~/tezos$ ./tezos-client bootstrapped
Current head: BLp58HCYrrSc (timestamp: 2020-04-01T19:19:25-00:00, validation: 2020-04-01T21:12:02-00:00)

Apr  1 12:43:50 - validator.peer: Worker started for NetXdQprcVkpa:idqxBjD6pLM5
Apr  1 12:43:50 - validator.block: Validation of block BM6BDR8a1fBgCKufUTovXafy228m4igbdVqSeXeZq6cQBPwx9qQ failed
Apr  1 12:43:50 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-04-01T19:43:50-00:00, treated in 6.697us, completed in 247ms , 
Apr  1 12:43:50 - validator.block: Inconsistent hash:
Apr  1 12:43:50 - validator.block:   got: CoUxJfUhEZSMt2CEs1s5T7mg2Z1kFPscJ4uM5mJvzCo74Cr6cHZB
Apr  1 12:43:50 - validator.block:   expected: CoW5so6fDEurK5wv8ayoHTJ4VonEfbDoaU9sb6rpPLFEDuifhHMW
Apr  1 12:43:50 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Unexpected error (validator):
Apr  1 12:43:50 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Error:
Apr  1 12:43:50 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Inconsistent hash:
Apr  1 12:43:50 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:     got: CoUxJfUhEZSMt2CEs1s5T7mg2Z1kFPscJ4uM5mJvzCo74Cr6cHZB
Apr  1 12:43:50 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:     expected: CoW5so6fDEurK5wv8ayoHTJ4VonEfbDoaU9sb6rpPLFEDuifhHMW
Apr  1 12:43:50 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: 
Apr  1 12:43:50 - validator.peer: Worker crashed [validator-peer_37145]:
Apr  1 12:43:50 - validator.peer: Inconsistent hash:
Apr  1 12:43:50 - validator.peer:   got: CoUxJfUhEZSMt2CEs1s5T7mg2Z1kFPscJ4uM5mJvzCo74Cr6cHZB
Apr  1 12:43:50 - validator.peer:   expected: CoW5so6fDEurK5wv8ayoHTJ4VonEfbDoaU9sb6rpPLFEDuifhHMW
Apr  1 12:43:51 - validator.block: Validation of block BM6BDR8a1fBgCKufUTovXafy228m4igbdVqSeXeZq6cQBPwx9qQ failed
Apr  1 12:43:51 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-04-01T19:43:51-00:00, treated in 3.561us, completed in 252ms , 
Apr  1 12:43:51 - validator.block: Inconsistent hash:
Apr  1 12:43:51 - validator.block:   got: CoUxJfUhEZSMt2CEs1s5T7mg2Z1kFPscJ4uM5mJvzCo74Cr6cHZB
Apr  1 12:43:51 - validator.block:   expected: CoW5so6fDEurK5wv8ayoHTJ4VonEfbDoaU9sb6rpPLFEDuifhHMW
```

Comment: This seems like a bug to open on gitlab.

Comment: Thanks utdrmac. Opened issue: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/754

Comment: I've seen a similar error on 32bits machines. What are the specs of the machine (Os, arch, cat /proc/cpuinfo ) you are running this node on and what is the output of `tezos-node --version` ?